# php replace ids in array

Tags: php, arrays

I got the following array:

```
"task" : {
    "author_id" : 150,
    "created_at" : somedate,
    "status_id" : 2,
    "assignee_id" : 100,
    "updated_at" : somedate_too
```

and I got 2 more associative arrays where I store names for IDs in the following way:

```
"100" => Mike,
"150" => Bob //etc..., the same for statuses
```

I need to check for the IDs in the first array and replace numbers with names for the corresponding arrays in the most effective way. I tried the following:

```
if(isset(task['status_id'])){$row = array_merge($row, [$status_ids[
  task['status_id']]]);}else{$row = array_merge($row, '');}

if(isset(task['author_id'])){row = array_merge($row, [$users[// note the different array here
  task['author_id']]]);}else{$row = array_merge($row, '');}

if(isset(task['assignee_id'])){$row = array_merge($row, [$users[
  task['assignee_id']]]);}else{$row = array_merge($row, '');}
```

In my resulting array ($row) I cannot miss the index and replace it with another value. If there is no value in the first array, I need to insert an empty string to get the following, for example:

```
['in progress', '', 'Mike']
```

if there is no author_id in the first array. I believe there should be a better way to do it with foreach loop, but I cant find out how because for different fields I get the data from different arrays. I dont think a separate if clause for every field is the most suitable here.
Any help would be welcome. Thank You.

Comment: You should not store data as code. Most types of database provide a means for resolving this problem usually with less code and effort than doing it in php.

Comment: acrtually it is a result from a db query. I am parsing many such 'tasks' and trying to map the ids with the corresponding names. Also the problem is that some data in some 'tasks' is omitted - say there is no assignee_id or author_id, and I need to leave the value blank in the array

Comment: RESOLVE THE DATA IN THE DATABASE

Comment: what do you mean? could you please explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could map your special keys to their array counterparts using references and use that mapping when populating `$row`, like this:

```
$users = [
    "100" => "Mike",
    "150" => "Bob",
];

$status_ids = [
    1 => "Foo",
    2 => "Bar",
];

// Define output format and array mapping
$mapping = [
    "author_id"   => &$users, // Mapped to $users array
    "created_at"  => null,    // Not mapped, keep $task value
    "status_id"   => &$status_ids,
    "assignee_id" => &$users,
    "updated_at"  => null,
];

$task = [
    "author_id"   => 150,
    "created_at"  => "Some date",
    "status_id"   => 2,
    // "assignee_id" => 99999, // Oops, missing key/value => empty string in $row
    "updated_at"  => "Some other date",
];

foreach ($mapping as $key => $mappedArray) {
    @$row[] = $mappedArray
        ? $mappedArray[$task[$key]] ?: ''
        : $task[$key];
}

print_r($row);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Bob
    [1] => Some date
    [2] => Bar
    [3] => 
    [4] => Some other date
)
```

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to do the same thing without the 3rd mapping array?

Comment: I'm not sure I quite follow. Which array do you mean?

Comment: The 3rd one, which you name $mapping. Btw, is result the same if one entry is omitted (say assignee_id is not 99999 but totally erased from the array - key and value)

Comment: `$mapping` is like the key to this solution as it connects `"author_id"` to the `$users` array etc. If you drop that variable, this solution won't work.

Comment: Regarding your second question; in that case, there will not be any (empty) value in `$row` for the assignee ID. If you want that functionality, you'll have to define the columns of the expected result (for example in the before-mentioned `$mapping`) and iterate over that array instead of `$task`. Without it there is no way for the program to tell what columns are expected in the output.

Comment: Right, I just saw your answer to that in a new comment on the question itself. I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

It should work (I didn't try it, but it should give you the general idea):

```
<?php

$fields = array("author_id", "assignee_id", "status_id");
$aliases = array("users", "users", "status_ids");

foreach ($task as $key=>&$value) {
    $alias = str_replace($fields, $aliases, ${$key});

    if (is_array(${$alias}) {
        $value = array_key_exists($value, ${$alias}) ? ${$alias}[$value] : "";
    }
}
unset($value);
```

And then you can fill up your `$row` as you planned, directly from the `$task` array.

Comment: Thank you for the idea. I`ll check it out and let you know